The 2024 Developer Survey
July 24, 2024 Update: The 2024 Dev Survey results are now live! We want to thank everyone again for their participation and cannot wait to see you next year.

Update: Due to the holiday and other factors, we have decided to extend the deadline to June 20th to provide more time for responses.

The 14th annual Developer Survey is open to the public today. 13 years ago Stack Overflow put out the first iteration of this survey. It had 19 questions, received ~2,500 responses, and SQL was the most popular programming language. Now with a few more questions, including a new section on embedded technology, we invite you to weigh in. The survey will remain open until June 20th, 2024.
Take the 2024 Developer Survey here.
Survey results will remain publicly available under the Open Database License.  You can find past year’s survey datasets on our insights page as well as on Kaggle. We’ll update both with the latest data once the survey results are available.
If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see some error messages. Our third-party survey provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you take the survey. Additionally, as a reminder, Qualtrics blocks certain countries from accessing their site and data. The list of blocked countries is: Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Syria, and the Crimea region of Ukraine (including Sevastopol). Finally, some users in China may have issues due to restrictions imposed by local internet service providers.
Note that, as with last year's survey, we will be asking a smaller quantity of personal demographic questions. If you discover any bugs in the survey or have any questions or concerns, please feel free to add them below this post as answers.

we will be asking a smaller quantity of personal demographic questions Hurray! I took the survey and was pleasantly surprised to see that the only personal questions (perhaps more in the optional part I didn't complete) were age, educational level and country - all of which are, IMHO, quite reasonable and relevant for a large company trying to figure who (and where) their users are.

What exactly is the incentive for me to take the web programming survey? You are asking me to spend my free time answering question that are completely irrelevant to my branch of programming and consequently I'm not interested in learning the results from the survey either. Why would I take this survey?

Cool that its out, I no longer participate in any developer survey from SO/SE just simply due to the direction this entire company has gone.

Nice to see HTMX on the list this time :) Especially since there are relatively little questions to the SO tag (which says more about how easy it is to learn and apply that tech rather than how popular it is).

Ukraine stats are obviously fake. See real numbers in 2021. The Survey became a joke.

I am a bit disappointed that you only ask further AI related questions to people that either use AI for development work or plan to use it.
It is quite possible for someone to have a good knowledge of how AI works, what are its downsides and upsides, can evaluate its usefulness, and even more being able to answer whether they are afraid that AI will jeopardize their job or not while at the same time not using it for development and work.
If it is not possible for changing this part in the current survey, then please do that for the next year's survey.

Indeed, right now my job involves developing AI but because we don't use AI tools that entire section was skipped.

Why would they allow users who are more likely to rate it poorly fill out that section? that's bad for marketing

@KevinB Obviously it depends on what the questions in that section actually are, but if I was designing a survey to see how people are using AI as part of the development process, then I would also want to know why they aren't using AI as well. There's a big difference between "I don't like the tools" and "Corporate policy doesn't allow the use of GenAI" or "The tools are too prone to hallucinations to be used in a secure computing environment."

As the survey denotes that the user doesn't use AI, then they can easily filter those results out, @KevinB . Plus, someone might not use AI because they had a terrible experience with it and therefore intentionally avoid it; those opinions do matter even if [so] thinks they don't, as OverflowAI in no way ever hallucinates.

@ThomA I don’t disagree that it’d be valuable information, but let’s keep in mind what the purpose of this survey is and always has been.

This. I actually went back and changed my answer just so I could answer the other AI questions. I have no plans to use AI at my job - also this doesn't mean I don't want to, it just means the higher-ups have told us not to because security and IP concerns.

@GregBurghardt I was surprised that I was allowed to answer the questionaire twice!

I am also heavily disappointed by the survey only suggesting "lack of executive buy-in" as a "challenge," and not considering the IT department having ipbanned all the AI services.

At the very least there should be a follow up question when I say "no" to using AI. "Why not?"

I was using AI but now am not. Where was that option?

They want to steer the conversation in favor of AI to say "see, developers love it, give us more money, AI companies."

It's deliberate sampling bias.

The frequency intervals (still) have a significant gap
This problem is still exactly the same as when it was reported each of the previous two years, so I'm just going to quote myself quoting Clonkex's answer from two years ago:

This problem is still exactly the same as when it was reported last year, so I'm just going to quote Clonkex's answer from last year's survey:

What's with these intervals? From 1-2 times a week to never? What about 1-2 times a month? None of the options fit my case. I don't interact outside my team very often (maybe once or twice a month) but when I do it's usually because of knowledge silos.



The quote nesting will continue until the response options improve.

I wish I could upvote this 1000 times! I just answered Never which is biassing the results.

I didn't get that question at all. Probably a feature ...

@ThomasWeller I believe it's triggered based on whether your responses meet some definition of being a "professional developer"

On the "What is your age" question:

The options are shown as checkboxes, but behave like radio buttons. In other questions, the radio buttons actually look like radio buttons, so why do the buttons on this question look like checkboxes?

The age of my body and what my mind feels my age is, are two different numbers.

This is not the only question with this problem (this is not intended to argue that it is correct, just that the fix should be applied across all questions that have this problem).

In my mind I'm 41, according to my ID I'm 51, when I try to do sports I feel like 61 and when talking with younger people, they make me feel like 81 :-)

If you only new how bad things are.. https://tonsky.me/blog/checkbox/

I comment on something similar at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430301/318414

In my mind I am 18 but body thinks it is 70. Sometimes my mind has a 10 year old schoolboys sense of humour.

Because you can be of any age and prefer not to say at the same time, in rare instances you can be halfway through the exact time of your birth (years later) while answering the question.

I faced an audit question that asked me to select the "Apples" answer.
I would like to know the statistic result of this particular question after the survey ends.
For example, how many people faced this question, how many get this question right, and how many get it wrong.

And how many have written "Apples" under Other, and how many have written Oranges there.

@DalijaPrasnikar Is that sarcasm? This guy asked a genuine question, you could have just said that you can just check it in the CSV or just not replied at all.

@SouradeepNanda No, it is not sarcasm, it is serious extension of the question asked in this answer. I know at least one person who did that.

I agree with both Dalija and this answer.  I was tempted to write in "Apples", but refrained.  I would be zero percent surprised if a nontrivial number of people did not refrain.  It would be quite interesting to see if there is a trend among the people who clearly read the question, but decided to answer in a more ...creative... way.

I have been through the survey twice. I did not get the salary question and got the Apples question both times.

I saw @DalijaPrasnikar's comment and then went to the survey. I got the apples question, answered Other and typed Apples. It didn't block me from answering the questions...

@LeonardoAlvesMachado the point is to filter out responses, at the analysis stage, from people/bots who aren't paying any attention whatsoever; calling attention to that by blocking further progress would somewhat defeat the purpose of the question.

Audits in the survey? No thanks, what a complete waste of time.

@DrewReese ehhh, it's a single question that specifically tells you, in advance, that it's an audit.  It's basically one of the old-style CAPTCHAs aimed at preventing the very dumbest bots by telling the user to "enter the answer to 1+1 in this box" and rejects anyone who doesn't answer "2".

@RyanM so, my answer to the survey might be ignored because of what I did? Or it accept the fact that I didn't select Apples but typed it in Others?

@LeonardoAlvesMachado It seems Ryan is saying that your entire survey response may be thrown out based on your answer to the audit question.

@LeonardoAlvesMachado I have no idea; only staff can answer that question.  I'm just saying that 1) I bet a bunch of people did the thing you did, and 2) I don't think having this question in the survey is problematic.  Were I analyzing the data, I would include typed-in "Apples" responses.

I know it can be skipped, but the question "Assign points to the following attributes of your job according to those that contribute the most to your satisfaction out of 100 total points" really needs to have an 'Other' option since the options provided make a lot of assumptions about what is motivating people.
I've known more than a handful of developers over the years that would say the most satisfying thing is the paycheck, and there are others that care less about the tools and more about what they are producing (e.g., a game developer getting satisfaction from the game they shipped and how it was reviewed).

I mean, you're not wrong, but if the point of the question is to see what things they cared about contributed to your satisfaction, listing things they don't care about would pollute the results.

I think that the most reasonable understanding of this question (as asked) is that you are rating the attributes' contribution to your satisfaction relative to the other listed attributes.  In that sense, "Other" would only make sense if you feel that none of the listed options contribute meaningfully to your satisfaction (which could be a reasonable response: perhaps one only cares about the money and nothing else; lots of people (not all!) in the financial sector have jobs that are only tolerable if that's the only thing one cares about...)

@RyanM That is one possible interpretation of the question, but it's bad survey design to make assumptions about how a respondent will interpret a question, practically considering the sample frame is an audience that's used to things being taken literally by the computer. :)

Erm. I took the survey about 6 hrs ago and don't remember seeing this question. Oopsy. Was this in the end opt-in section?

I was about to say the same thing as @QHarr about not seeing that question.


How do you learn to code? Select all that apply.

How do I currently learn how to code (i.e. build upon my existing knowledge of how to code)?  Or how have I gotten my knowledge of how to code to the point where it's at?
As someone who has been coding for multiple decades, the answers to the two are very different.
I learned to code primarily from physical books, and from university courses, and from reading API documentation.  I almost never do the first any more, I'm not in university so I don't do the second, and I do the third but it's more about making me more aware of existing and new features in the ecosystem and not "learning to code".
Professionally, I've learned much of what I've needed to know day-to-day by Googling it and reading about it on Stack Overflow and blogs.  And that's currently my main way of finding stuff out.
It's arguable that I'm not even really "learning to code" at this point in my life, so much as learning new frameworks and technologies and fitting them into my already existing knowledge of "how to code".

Learning to code is a journey not an event!

I had the same question. I just answered it as how do I currently learn to code, since that's the way it was worded.

What is meant by "Overflow API"?
The question "Which of the following Stack Overflow sites have you visited? Select all that apply." has, as one of the options, "Overflow API".
There is no site or product by this exact name.  It may refer to:

This page promoting OverflowAPI (note: no space), "a subscription-based API service that provides continuous access to Stack Overflow’s public dataset to train and fine-tune large language models."  However, that doesn't exactly seem like a "site".
Whatever non-public documentation, if any, may exist for the OverflowAPI product described on that page.
The Stack Exchange API.  This would make the most sense to ask about as a site that one might have visited in a public survey, but it is the furthest from the name used.


If it's the SE API, it'd be great if it could be clarified if the survey meant whether a user visited a documentation page for it or whether they've accessed an API endpoint. There's (presumably) some set of people that use userscripts involving the API, but don't develop using the API.

I found the options for this question to be quite sparse. There was no mention about other sites on the SE network, so I took the SE site option to mean other SE sites besides Stack Overflow and answered accordingly.

Consider renaming "Professional degree" to "Doctoral degree" or "Doctorate" since an academic Ph.D. is not generally considered a professional degree.
Also, nit: In the professional degree list, the use of periods is either inconsistent (JD and MD) or incorrect (Ph.D and Ed.D).


Either drop all periods
Or use periods consistently/correctly

JD -> J.D.
MD -> M.D.
Ph.D -> Ph.D.
Ed.D -> Ed.D.




Should I write PhD or Ph.D. ?

Is this only asking about use of tools in a work or other programming context?
The question "Which communication tools did you use regularly over the past year, and which do you want to work with over the next year?" includes a number of options that are very commonly used in both a professional/programming context, as well as contexts related to neither work nor programming.  For example, I use Discord to talk to friends, but I have never used it for anything related to work or programming.

same thing with WhatsApp & co

just answer the question as written. WhatsApp mst be on everybody's list

Maybe since the survey has ended someone can remove this reminder :)

This post says extended to June 20th but clicking the link above shows survey has ended.


Looks like it's been fixed in the meantime! I can access it again.

Just now I got this reminder, clicked it out of curiosity and wasn't able to take the survey again.

Pretty sure you put some stuff related to C and C++ in an unintended section: Boost.Test, build2, Catch2, CMake, cppunit, doctest, GNU GCC, Clang, Meson, MSVC, Ninja, QMake, Scons. You put them under embedded (which... technically isn't wrong since you might use this stuff doing embedded development) when they'd make much more sense under build and test.
Probably too late to fix this in the input form, but at least you could try to move it in the results. I think it might be embarrassing for you otherwise.

Conversely, Zephyr is somewhere else than the embedded section.

The majority of that stuff has nothing to do with embedded systems and are explicitly not used for such.

The fact that Cargo was also in that section, instead of the build tools section also seems rather weird. Sure if you are using Rust for embedded then you will probably be using Cargo, but that is less because you are doing embedded dev and more because you are using Rust.

"Thinking about how your job and process changes over time, how integrated in your workflow do you anticipate AI tools you are currently using will be 1 year from now?"
This question uses check-boxes, but surely should be radio buttons? Also perhaps the previous question that the options are based on -- but I can see the argument either way for that one



I don't recall whether or not they are, but are they perhaps radio buttons disguised as check boxes?

nope - see pictures

Ah, yes, that's...definitely wrong.


Which other frameworks and libraries have you done extensive development work in over the past year, and which do you want to work in over the next year?

This question has "Ruff" as an option, but Ruff is neither a framework nor a library.

The first section asks for my current status, I selected "Retired". One of the last questions I was asked was about my current position. As I have retired none of the options suited, so I had to enter that in the "Other" box.

The estimate of 15 minutes I think is well low. I think it took me about 25 minutes to finish, having to take time to consider the myriad platforms and frameworks and so on, and that's even saying no to the AI question, so I didn't get to answer that section.

Which of these company challenges causes you the most frustration? Select all that apply.
I am strongly missing options for anything related to quality assurance.
Or was it left out, because too many would check it, if even just out of resentment?
Jokes aside, in my company, QA is a major challenge, because we are doing archive migrations. Therefore, we have to interface with legacy systems that we often don't have direct access to in early development phases and usually our options for deployment are quite limited, too. This make it really hard to assess the correctness of anything we build, which then usually spreads to other departments in the company, because for example how do you plan a project with that?

A question asks

What is the source of the technical documentation you use most often to learn to code?
Select all that apply.

And these are the possible answers:

API document(s) and/or SDK document(s)
User guides or README files found in the source repository
First-party knowledge base
Traditional public search engine
AI-powered search/dev tool (free)
AI-powered search/dev tool (paid)
Other (please specify)

I don't understand the difference between 1) and 3). What's the difference between "API/SDK documents" and "first-party knowledge base"? They seem the same thing to me.

I would read "first-party knowledge base" as something akin to a corporate wiki or e.g. SOfTeams instance at your own place of work; maybe that's what they mean?

It could also mean something like https://answers.microsoft.com/.  The meaning is definitely ambiguous.

I read 1) as "normative" and 3) as "non-normative", but in retrospect I agree that it is ambiguous.

The survey results site has several problems. I still have not gone through the survey completely, so here just few ones I noticed:

(On Firefox) Charts with multiple tabs do not show any data until you switch between the tabs.

Clicking on "community" on the main page tiles leads to an error page GIF of "community is undefined".

The problem is that the URL is apparently case-sensitive: clicking the tile leads to https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2024/Community/ with a capital "C" which does not work. While https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2024/community/ with a lowercase "C" does work.


Some charts show very suspicious numbers of responses that I do not believe can be correct. For example in "Frequency of participation on Stack Overflow" there are four tabs, each has the number of responses in the lower right. Here they are:

All Respondents: 45,237 (69.1%)

Professional Developers: 4,139 (6.3%)

Learning to Code: 4,139 (6.3%)

Other Coders: 45,237 (69.1%)
I find it extremely unlikely that "Professional" and "Learning" have the exact same number of responses. Even if they do, I do not think it possible that "All" and "Other" are the same.  
I found a similar thing in other questions - the exact same number of responses for two different tabs, however I cannot reliably reproduce it. I think the "Frequency of participation on Stack Overflow" question has consistently wrong.



The "Previous" link at the bottom goes to the current page you're on. For example, if you are in the "Work" section, the Previous link leads to "Work". The Next link does go to the next section.


This is an incomplete list of just few things I noticed.

Thank you for flagging some issues with the survey site here.  We were able to fix that link to the Community page you outlined in the linked gif and updated those total numbers for a few of the charts that were displaying incorrect total respondents for some segments (percentages were displaying correctly).
The issue with charts not showing up will need to be looked at, but could not be fixed immediately.  The "Previous" link issue is working as intended.

@ErinAsks Just to confirm that we're seeing the same behavior, regarding "The 'Previous' link issue is working as intended.": it's supposed to behave like this?  That is, it's not supposed to actually change what page you're on, just reload the current page and then scroll down to a slightly higher location?

@RyanM - very good confirming, that behavior was not intended.  A fix is now being deployed.

On the questions about what language/framework/etc I use now vs what I want to be using in a year, the “want” always confuses me. Does it really mean “want”, as in even if I stop working I’d continue to play around with it or if I switch jobs I’d try to introduce it at my new employer, or is it more what will I be working with in a year, which could be because I want to, or more likely, because that’s what the company I work for uses?

“Wants” are rarely independent of all other considerations. I may want to work with a tool because I genuinely like it. I may want to work with a tool to keep current and increase my future employment opportunities. I may want to work with a tool because it’s what my current employer uses and I like where I’m working, even if I don’t particularly like the tool. Or some combination of those.

Who knows. For years they’ve used this line of questioning to determine what languages developers like/hate, despite not indicating that in the question at all.

It doesn't need to be indicated in the question. The problem is that they're analysing the data incorrectly. They treat not picking "want" as "don't want" when it more often than not doesn't mean that. There's plenty of things I've used in the past year that I don't want to work with, but also don't want to avoid working with. They're applying the wrong meaning to the "want" checkbox, and have been for years. This has also been commented on several times in the past, and they so far haven't cared. We'll see if this year's analysis is any different, but I strongly doubt it.

It's just two worded completely uselessly, so they can make up whatever meaning they want, rather than what the users might mean.

The questions about the technologies that we "do extensive development work in" are ambiguous. For example:

Which embedded systems and technologies have you done extensive development work in over the past year, and which do you want to work in over the next year?

In the last year I've been working on a project that is built using QMake (which is on the list). Do I do extensive development with it? I'm not sure what you mean!
Sometimes I compile tens of times per day. And yet, I've never modified a single .pro file, except for really trivial stuff, like adding a new source file to the list of the existing ones. I've never changed compiler flags, linker flags, options, paths, dependencies, anything: all of these things were set up by others long before I joined the project.
So QMake is used in my project, yes, but not really by me, or at most in a very passive way. Does that count as "doing extensive development work with it"?

The question regarding the compensation, it does not mention which currency I should input my compensation in. Though it asks for my currency, it does not make it obvious whether or not the currency I choose here is the one to be considered for the compensation field.
Does anyone know what currency applies to the compensation field?


Judging by the wording preceding the currency selection ("estimating in"), and the wording of the compensation input box ("please estimate") as well as my own common sense - I'd say, while it is not explicit, it is fairly obvious that the currency you chose is what you're expected to use in the number field.

I am also 97.8% sure that the currency selected in the dropdown above is the one to be considered for the compensation field. But I would still maintain that the wording should been clearer, sth along the lines of "What is your current total annual compensation in the currency you selected above...". All I am saying is when making a survey that is going to be taken by millions, everything should be stated as clearly as possible.

This is a very good point. It's worrying to see that this has been downvoted on a developer site. The Design of Everyday Things should be a mandatory reading. The problem is not whether it's obvious or not, but the very fact that you even have to pause to think about it is bad UX.

@MaciejKravchyk Exactly! Those who downvoted this are probably not very precise in their communications and probably don't care about being precise either.

I also decided it could obviously only be in the currency I had just chosen but I did wonder since it wasn't explicitly mentioned.

@MaciejKravchyk Indeed! One of the best timesavers I have learned is how to answer questions like "on a scale of 1 to 10 ..." No need to think about whether it is a 3 or a 4 just answer either 1 or 10. The intermediate answers are fairly useless to the question setter anyway.

On this question:

Which of the following describes your current job, the one you do most
of the time? Please select only one.

There isn't anything between an Engineering Manager and Senior Executive (C-Suite, VP, etc). In my opinion a director role does not fit well in either of this. I used the Other (please specify): option, but I guess this is a somewhat common answer that deserves its radio button (and this would make sure people don't write it out differently).

I can take the survey twice! Is it by design? If it is, why?

probably not quite "by design" in the sense of "yes, we really want you to do this!". more like- I don't see how they could totally prevent you from doing this. even if you had to log into something to submit a response, you could just make multiple accounts. maybe simple cases could be prevented by setting a flag in localstorage that you've submitted a response to this particular survey already on this machine (even then, it's not hard to edit localstorage).

@starball: well, while we can't probably prevent developers from answering multiple times, it would have been nice to set a cookie (or similar) that I already answered. Now I get that stupid banner each time I visit, although I already answered.

It would have been nice to have been sent your responses. This way, I can observe my own changes over time as well as feed my AI Dev Coach.
